# How to set the slider width inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I use the code below to visualise the connection between a sine curve and the unit circle, but would like to make the slider wider, so it has at least almost the same with as the image. I have tried to replace ControlType->Slider[] with ControlType -> Slider[ImageSize->800], but this seems to have no effect at all och the resulting graphics. The question is thus how to set the width of the slider inside Manipulate?

```
Manipulate[
 With[{ar = 1/(2*Pi), o = v - Cos[v]}, 
  Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6*Pi, 6*Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"v", Sin["v"]}, AspectRatio -> ar],
   ListLinePlot[{{o + Cos[v], 0}, {o + Cos[v], Sin[v]}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, AspectRatio -> ar],
   ListLinePlot[{{o + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {o, 0}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}, AspectRatio -> ar],
   Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{o, 0}]}, AspectRatio -> ar],
   Plot[{-Sqrt[1 - (x - o)^2], Sqrt[1 - (x - o)^2]}, {x, o - 1, 
     o + 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Orange}}, 
    AspectRatio -> ar], ImageSize -> 800]], {v, -3/2*Pi, 3/2*Pi}, 
 ControlType -> Slider[]]
```

[image: The resulting graphics]

Comment: you mean like that: `{v, -3/2*Pi, 3/2*Pi, ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> 800}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to study the documentation carefully, but I agree that help-pages like the one of `Manipulate` are very densely packed with information. In the *Details and Options* section you find how to set options for controls:

> ```
> {{u,...},...,opts}    control with particular options
> ```

The non-obvious part is, that you have to set the `ControlType` as well to make this work. Therefore, you can use

```
{v, -3/2*Pi, 3/2*Pi, ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> 800}
```

to achieve the wanted behavior. Another way is to replace `Manipulate` by a full `DynamicModule` which is a bit more code but gives you some more flexibility

```
DynamicModule[{v = -3/2 Pi, o},
 o = v - Cos[v];
 Panel@
  With[{ar = 1/(2*Pi)},
   Column[{
     Slider[Dynamic[v, (v = #; o = v - Cos[v]; &)], {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
      ImageSize -> 800],
     Dynamic@
      Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6*Pi, 6*Pi}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
        AxesLabel -> {"v", Sin["v"]}, AspectRatio -> ar], 
       ListLinePlot[{{o + Cos[v], 0}, {o + Cos[v], Sin[v]}}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, AspectRatio -> ar],
       ListLinePlot[{{o + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {o, 0}}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}, AspectRatio -> ar], 
       Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{o, 0}]}, 
        AspectRatio -> ar], 
       Plot[{-Sqrt[1 - (x - o)^2], Sqrt[1 - (x - o)^2]}, {x, o - 1, 
         o + 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
        PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Orange}}, 
        AspectRatio -> ar], ImageSize -> 800, Background -> White]
     }]
   ]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This will work. The only change is that I removed the option ControlType and added a "slider function" at the end of the control for v. Note that Pinguin Dirks suggestion in the comments also works, is more convenient and he beat me to it :). Still I guess this code shows how you can have even more control over your slider.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{ar = 1/(2*Pi), o = v - Cos[v]}, 
  Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6*Pi, 6*Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"v", Sin["v"]}, AspectRatio -> ar], 
   ListLinePlot[{{o + Cos[v], 0}, {o + Cos[v], Sin[v]}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, AspectRatio -> ar], 
   ListLinePlot[{{o + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {o, 0}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}, AspectRatio -> ar], 
   Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{o, 0}]}, AspectRatio -> ar],
    Plot[{-Sqrt[1 - (x - o)^2], Sqrt[1 - (x - o)^2]}, {x, o - 1, 
     o + 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Orange}}, 
    AspectRatio -> ar], ImageSize -> 800]], {v, -3/2*Pi, 3/2*Pi, 
  Slider[Dynamic[v], {-3/2*Pi, 3/2*Pi}, ImageSize -> 800] &}]
```