# How to make `Manipulate[]` slider longer but not losing buttons?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24499/how-to-set-the-slider-width-inside-manipulate) the solution to make `Manipulate`'s slider longer is to use `ControlType->Slider` with `ImageSize` option. But I need to also have it expandable so that I could view and enter the numeric value. I've tried setting `ControlType->Manipulator`, but for some reason `ImageSize` stops working in this case.

Here's an example code which works with `ControlType->Slider`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 0.2],
    {a, -10, 10, ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> 800}]
```

How do I make the manipulator longer but still retain the controls under `+` button?

Comment: please provide a minimal example to use as starting point.

Comment: @Nasser, added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I need to also have it expandable so that I could view and enter
>   the numeric value

Maybe I am missing something, but why use `ControlType` for? Is this what you mean?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 0.2],
 {a, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 600}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You seem to be using version 10. Maybe they've fixed it there, but your code doesn't work for me on version 9. And only specifying `ControlType` to `Slider` makes the size correct for me.

Comment: @Ruslan yes, I am using V10.01 on windows 7 (time to upgrade then ;)